# Connecting django to a webservice instead of database

Tags: django, web-services, orm, django-models, django-views

We want to replace the django database layer with a webservice and we want to do this as smoothly as possible. Basically django will handle all the HTTP requests, sessions, templates, authentication etc and the webservice will handle everything related to the database.

How do you suggest would be the best way to do this without redoing much of the existing code ? Did anyone do something similar ? I assume due to the django loose coupling this should be doable.

The main reason we want to do this is because we have more java developers than django developers so we are thinking of doing the webservice in java. This is by far the best way to use our companies resources, the question is how to do it the best way. The project is young and we expect it to grow a lot in complexity so on the long-term splitting our developers this way is the best for us.

Thanks,
   Roger

Answer (score 1):

At my company, we work with Django exclusively and in a completely decoupled fashion. Our webservices are powered by Pyramid + Cornice and we leverage the excellent [Python-Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library to interact with our service layer.

Authentication and permissions for apps are done with [Authentic2](http://packages.python.org/authentic2/) and ADFS using a custom backend that we developed.

As such, we don't have any model objects in our apps, but we can still leverage all of the goodness of Django forms and formsets.

Our webservices return JSON, so it's very simple for us to pass lists of key value pairs to templates and also to supply initial data to forms, etc. It's really no different than returning values or values_lists from a Django ORM call.

As far as I know, there's not a drop-in replacement to write a Django model class that is connecting to a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this project after seeing your post http://code.larlet.fr/django-roa/wiki/Home
Seems to be the exact thing you are looking for.